# limit infimum as $x\to \infty$

Tags: calculus

If $$\liminf_{x\to \infty}f(x)>M,$$ for some $M>0$, where $f$ is continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

Does this imply that: there exist $x_{o}$ such that for all $x\geq x_{o}$ we have $f(x)>M$? If so, how I can prove it?

I also have another question, just to be sure: If $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, both are continuous on $\mathbb R$, then
 $\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x)\leq \liminf_{x\to\infty} g(x)$

Comment: Write down the definition of $\liminf$. Then try to assume that what you wrote is false. That is there is a sequence of $x_n$ going to infinity with $f(x_n)<=M$.

Comment: I know that the first argument is true for sequences: If $\liminf_{n\to \infty}x_{n}>M$ then there exists $n_{o}$ such that $x_{n}>M$ for all $n\geq n_{o}$. But is it true also for functions!?

Comment: Using Alex R.'s argument, a contradiction will happen.  However, I'm going to do this question in another way for fun.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $L = \liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \sup_{N>0}\inf_{x\ge N}f(x)$.  Then we have $L>M$, so $M$ *isn't* a supremum of $\left\{\inf_{x\ge N}f(x)\mid N>0\right\}$.  Therefore, $\exists x_0>0$ such that $\inf_{x\ge x_0}f(x)>M$.  Hence, $f(x) > M \;\forall x \ge x_0$.
2. The answer is yes.  We're given
   $$f(x)\leq g(x) \;\forall x \in \Bbb R.\tag{1}$$
   Let $N>0$.  We first take infimum on the LHS over all $x\ge N$.
   $$\inf_{x\ge N}f(x) \le g(x) \;\forall x \ge N\tag{2}$$
   Then $\inf_{x\ge N}f(x)$ is a lower bound of $\left\{g(x)\mid x \ge N\right\}$, while $\inf_{x\ge N}g(x)$ is the *greatest* lower bound of $\left\{g(x)\mid x \ge N\right\}$.  Therefore, one has
   $$\inf_{x\ge N}f(x) \le \inf_{x\ge N}g(x).\tag{3}$$
   From (1) to (3), we realize that we can take infimum on both sides.  Similarly, we can take supremum over $N>0$ on both sides.
   $$\sup_{N>0}\inf_{x\ge N}f(x) \le \sup_{N>0}\inf_{x\ge N}g(x)\tag{4}$$
   In other words, we have the statement in the OP.
   $$\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x) \le \liminf_{x\to\infty}g(x)$$